# NHibernate Intercept SQL Statement and Parameters

Tags: nhibernate, interceptor

This question is almost the same as [Intercept SQL statements containing parameter values generated by NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048835/intercept-sql-statements-containing-parameter-values-generated-by-nhibernate) but with no answer so far yet.

```
Public Class SqlStatementInterceptor
    Inherits EmptyInterceptor
    Implements IInterceptor

    Public Overrides Function OnPrepareStatement(sql As SqlString) As SqlString
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - {1}", DateTime.Now, sql.ToString()))
        Return sql
    End Function
End Class
```

I can capture SQL statementm, but does not seem to be able to get parameters. Anybody ever tried to achieve it?

Comment: @Felice Pollano I could, but not ideal. Because I implement unit test by using SQLite (in production code I use SQL Server), it might be faster to show the statement in VS output window.

Comment: you can, have a look at the reply. No needing to create a special appender if you just want to see what happens

Answer (score 4):

You need to write log4net appender. This is how NHProf gets the information. There is also project on codeplex called [NHibernate 3.0 SQL Logger](http://nh3sqllogger.codeplex.com/) which uses that technique.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `log4net` with a `TraceAppender`, and also the `format_sql=true` property in configuration that help in readability. The logger to use is `NHibernate.SQL`.