# Do any .NET ORM's or ADO.NET frameworks support connection retries?

Tags: sql-server, orm, ado.net

I have started using SQL Server 2012's Always On feature and during a failure, the server database connection is down for about 15 seconds during the failover transition.

During that period, all queries in the middle of executing and all new connections will fail... so the client applicaiton would ideally support retrying the connection if it detects that the failover is occuring.

Are there any frameworks or ORMs that can handle this situation automatically?

Comment: Seems like NHibernate [might be a good bet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774221/how-do-i-add-retry-logic-in-nhibernate-to-handle-transient-failures-in-sql-azure)

Comment: I found an Azure solution (Transient Fault Handling Application Block) at [link](http://nuget.org/packages/EnterpriseLibrary.Source.WindowsAzure). I was hoping for an ADO.NET or Entity Framework solution (ie, Microsoft provided).