# NHibernate Interceptor -> Output Query with Parameters

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nhibernate, interceptor

How do I implement an Interceptor that outputs the query WITH parameters? I have searched the web and stackoverflow for a long time now and haven´t found an answer to my problem. My Custom Interceptor-Class looks like this at the moment:

```
public class SQLDebugOutput : EmptyInterceptor, IInterceptor {
        public override NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString OnPrepareStatement(NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlString sql) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("NH: " + sql.ToString());
            return base.OnPrepareStatement(sql);
        }
}
```

The parameters in the query are displayed as questionmarks though and I need them for debugging purposes. Also I´d prefer a solution not using the Log4Net Logger.

**So, is it possible at all to retrieve the parameter values of a query using an interceptor at all? Maybe by overriding other methods of it?**

Comment: You mean the ShowSql() Option?

Comment: Yes, we are using Log4Net and I have read about creating a new Appender to log the nhibernate-queries - but I´d like to know if it is possible to get the parameters of the queries via Interceptor or not.

Comment: Thanks anyway - I read your answer after posting my previous comment. Any ideas on how to implement a similar functionality via interceptor?

Answer (score 0):

The `SqlString` type that's supplied as a parameter to the `OnPrepareStatement` method has a `GetParameters()` method that returns a collection of `Parameter` objects. Looking at the code suggests it should be possible to interrogate these objects and, hopefully, find what you're looking for.

Comment: Saying that... there's no obvious property on the `Parameter` type that represents the current value.

Comment: unfortunately sql.GetParameters() just returns the parameters as questionmarks and not the actual parameter values. I had already checked that - would have been to easy :-)

Comment: Sure. Just as I posted the answer I took a closer look and saw the same. There must be some way of getting the information as the parameter values get logged when logging's enabled.

Comment: that´s what I thought, too, but it seems to be quite hard actually. Any ideas?

Comment: There's an interesting idea here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048835/intercept-sql-statements-containing-parameter-values-generated-by-nhibernate), looking at doing it with a subclassed database provider.